# Django, queryset to find count in manytomany field

Tags: python, django

I have below model,

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    head = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

How do I find authors count ?

Let us say I have an Entry object as `Entryobject` (`Entryobject = Entry.objects.filter(blog__name='a')`
), I tried as below but got attribute error.

```
Entryobject.authors.count() # got error here
```

Also please let me know how can I query list of authors in Entryobject .

Comment: It should be Entryobject = Entry.objects.filter(Blog__name='a') with a uppercase B, shouldn't it?

Comment: yes,  thats entry object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query a list of authors like so:

```
Entryobject = Author.objects.all() or
Entryobject = Author.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Regarding `flat=True` I'd like to reference the official [docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/). Basically it returns a Queryset with single values rather than tuples, example:

```
>>> Entry.objects.values_list('id').order_by('id')
<QuerySet[(1,), (2,), (3,), ...]>

>>> Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
<QuerySet [1, 2, 3, ...]>
```

Also regarding your error, I think it should be an uppercase `B`:

```
Entryobject = Entry.objects.filter(Blog__name='a')
```